# Excel 2010 formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need help with a formula for the following:

L6 needs to show a date which is the date in K6 + the value (days) in J6. However if there is no data or only text in either K6 or J6, cell L6 should be blank.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? try and have a look at the IF function. to calculate with dates you just sum the date + the amount of days.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Generally, it is good practice to use a cell for a specific purpose.  You describe J6 and K6 as potentially containing either date-related information (I assume not mixed with something else), or text (and you don't describe the nature of the potential text).  Without knowing what could potentially be in the cells, there is no practical way to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the noob response! I have edited this post into oblivion!

Try Copy & Pasting the following into Cell L6:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(J6), ISBLANK(K6)), "", K6+J6)
```

As one of the commenters pointed out, if one of the cells are formatted a text value as opposed to General/Short/Long date, you will get an error. One way to override this is by converting the contents into K6 and J6 into values before adding them together. So, we go from the above formula to:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(J6), ISBLANK(K6)), "", VALUE(J6)+VALUE(K6))
```

This, however will give us a five-digit number which tells us the number of calendar days since 1/1/1900. Then, format this cell as a Date (either short or long).

If, however, you would like to preserve the end result in text format, use the following:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(J6), ISBLANK(K6)), "", TEXT(VALUE(J6)+VALUE(K6), "MM/DD/YYYY"))
```

Comment: When I type in this formula it comes out with an error and highlights the first comme (,) between (J6) and ISBLANK...

Comment: The formula is have at the moment is

Comment: The formula I is have at the moment is as simple as:

=[Last Cal Date (MMYYYY)]+[Cal Interval (Days)]

(last cal date is column 6, Cal interval is column J)

Comment: So what I need now, is a formula that does the same as above but if J6 (Cal Interval (Days) is empty the target cell should be left empty.

Comment: The column J can have a number (of days) or the text DO NOT CAL.

Comment: @TheExcelMentor
I tried to use the formulas above, but I get the same error as described yesterday :-( - It highlights the first comme (,) between (J6) and ISBLANK...